# ObjC class method is not called. GDB playing games?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, gdb

I have a custom UITableViewController that I am trying to use to manage a UITableView. The flow of my code in the main UIViewController that contains the UITableView goes like below:

```
    _messagesTableVC = [[AllMessagesTableViewController alloc] init];

    _allMessageTableView.dataSource = _messagesTableVC;
    _allMessageTableView.delegate = _messagesTableVC;

    [_allMessageTableView reloadData];
```

The `AllMessagesTableViewController` custom UITableViewController class is initialized, it does any processing needed and I set the `_allMessageTableView` (the UITableView)'s delegates to my custom class.

When I run this code, the program acts as if the custom class is not there but no errors occur. It seems as that NO methods in the custom class are called, no init, no initWithCoder, nothing (I have set breakpoints and checked ;)).

As you can see in the screenshot below, I have set a breakpoint after a custom method `refreshData` in the custom class that I set to return `YES`. I assign the return value of `refreshData` to a local variable `test`.

In the debugger:

1. `_messagesTableVC` custom class does not appear to be nil.
2. `test` does not appear to exist.
3. Not shown here, but when I try to run `[_messagesTableVC refreshData]` in the debugger it says `error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
   The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.`. So is `_messagesTableVC` actually nil??

[image: screenshots]

What could be causing these problems or is GDB playing games? This is a Messages app extension in case that makes any difference. Thanks.

**Update: Here is the code for the custom class init and refreshData**

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self)
        return nil;
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)refreshData {
    return YES;
}
```

**Update2:** I created a blank working project and copy pasted the exact files into my original project (because it is an iMessage extension to a big iOS app). It turns out the Xcode is running the older build of the app even after I cleaned the project and changed the UITableView delegate to supply a different text.
[image: more]

Comment: Could you post your code for `-refreshData`?  And are you sure that the `-init` method in AllMessagesTableViewController isn't being hit?  or is that not what you meant?

Comment: Also side note, it looks like you are using LLDB as your debugger, not GDB (but not relevant to your question IMO)

Comment: @AO I have updated my question to include the `init` and `refreshData` methods. Yes, I create simple `init` and `refreshData` methods but nothing is run, weirdly. I have made sure that am importing the right files, too.

Comment: Yeah that is weird.  Would you mind zipping up your workspace and uploading it?  I could probably find your issue if I ran your code.  If you have proprietary stuff don't sweat it

Comment: And another note, with formatted strings in objective-c, `%@` looks for an `NSObject`.  `BOOL` is a primitive data type, so that's why you are getting that compiler warning.  You can replace that line with: `NSLog(@"Test: %@", test ? @"YES : @"NO")`.  The ternary operator (`?`) will set the string to "YES" or "NO" depending on the state of `test`

Comment: Why are you instantiating a view controller but not presenting it or is not really a view controller?  Your test has probably been released since you appear to be at the end of the method and there is no further reference to the local variable after assignment.  How is _messagesTableVC declared? Is there are reason you are accessing the iVar directly and. Glass in the setter/getter?

Comment: @AO I created a new project and ran the same setup without any problems. But after copying the exact code into the original project, same issues appeared but I got a visual confirmation that Xcode is running an older build of my app even though I have made sure to clean the project. Any idea what could be causing this problem? I created a Message Extension target the same project in the past, deleted it and readded it.

Comment: @Paulw11 I created a custom UITableViewController to handle the main UIViewController's UITableView methods. `_messagesTableVC` is declared as a property in the main UIViewController.

Comment: What was the visual confirmation that it was running an older build?  Like you changed the UI but it wasn't reflected in the app?  Something's definitely funky if your `-init` isn't even being hit.  Can you set a breakpoint  at the `alloc] init]` and step in? (I'm off to bed now but I can keep trying to help you figure it out tomorrow)

Comment: Have you made progress?

Comment: @AO I was able to fix the issue by completely removing and re-adding the Messages Extension target to the project. I will post it in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Messages Extension for the same project in the past and deleted the target while keeping the files in the project. When I re-added the Messages Extension to the project, Xcode kept running the older build of the app.
I fixed the issue with Xcode running an older version of the app by:

1. Clean All
2. Delete Messages Extension target from project
3. Backup existing Message Extension code to a directory outside the project. Then delete the Messages app group and directory from the project.
4. Delete the Messages Extension build scheme from project.
5. Delete project Derived Data directory.
6. Restart Xcode, create new Messages Extension target in project, and import saved code.